# OneAPI 2022's GNU Compiler Collection support are missing

Tags: macos, gnu, intel-mkl, intel-oneapi, oneapi

I have tried to install the [latest OneAPI base toolkit](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/base-toolkit-download.html) for MacOS. I need to compile a program that uses **OpenMP threading library (mkl_gf_lp64)** for the GNU Fortran compiler and **LP64 interface library (mkl_gnu_thread)** for GNU fortran and C++ compilers.

According to [this manual](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-linux-developer-guide/top/appendix-c-directory-structure-in-detail/structure-of-the-intel-64-architecture-directories/static-libraries-in-the-lib-intel64-lin-directory.html) for Linux these are supposed to be installed automatically, but after installing the OneAPI base toolkit I cannot locate any of these library files: libmkl_gf_lp64.a and libmkl_gnu_thread.a
They are parts of *GNU Compiler collection support* and it seems to be missing in MacOS installation package of OneAPI and OneMKL (During installation, I selected all available packages).

Does anyone know how I can include these library files in the OneAPI base installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GNU Compiler collection support is an optional component for OneMKL in the Linux system, but it seems they are [not available under the MacOS](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-macos-developer-guide/top/appendix-c-directory-structure-in-detail/static-libraries-in-the-lib-directory.html).

It is possible to use [MKL Link Line advisor](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/onemkl-link-line-advisor.html) to find the appropriate libraries for each environment.

In my case, I used mkl_intel_lp64 and mkl_intel_thread instead of the above-mentioned libraries.

More information is available at [this post](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Math-Kernel-Library/OneAPI-compiler-fails-to-locate-libraries-quot-mkl-gf-lp64-quot/m-p/1376787#M33018) of Intel Support communities.